# About the Fibonacci's numbers identity ${n \choose k}_F = F_{n-k+1}{n-1 \choose k-1}_F+F_{k-1} {n-1 \choose k}_F$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to prove, in a combinatorial way, this identity for fibonomial coefficients, when $0\lt k \lt n $:

$${n \choose k}_F = F_{n-k+1}{n-1 \choose k-1}_F+F_{k-1} {n-1 \choose k}_F$$

where $F_n$ is defined by $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, $\,\,\,F_0=0, \,\,\,\,F_1 =1$ and $${n \choose k}_F = \frac{n!_F}{k!_F(n-k)!_F}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n!_F=F_1F_2\dots F_n$$

It's well known that the $F_n$ counts the number of coverings of a board $(n-1)\times1$ with squares and dominoes and I have already proved that $F_n = F_{n-k+1}F_{k-2}+F_{k-1}F_{n-k}$ by considering when the $(k-1)$th slot of the board is covered either with one or the other kind of tile.

It's clear that the fibotorial $n!_F$ enumerates the number of tilings, with squares and dominoes, of a upper-triangular board $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ and, it has been quite harder, but I showed that the fibonomial is an integer number by "cutting away" the number of coverings of a $(k-1)\times(k-1)$ upper triangular board from $n!_F$.

Now I want to conclude  that ${n-1 \choose k-1}_F = F_{k-2}$ and ${n-1 \choose k}_F =F_{n-k}$ by assembling the two results, I can do that algebraically, but how to see it in a combinatorial way?

Comment: FWIW, I believe this was done combinatorially in a recent talk by Bruce Sagan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial interpretation of $\binom{n}{k}_F$. All of this is taken from the source cited at the end. Quoting Theorem $2$ from the article,

> For $a, b ≥ 1,$ $\binom{a+b}{a}_F$ counts the ways to draw a lattice path from $(0, 0)$ to $(a, b)$,
> then tile each row above the lattice path with squares and dominos, then tile each column below
> the lattice path with squares and dominos, with the restriction that the column tilings are not
> allowed to start with a square.

This interpretation can be proved by induction, using the identity ${n \choose k}_F = F_{n-k+1}{n-1 \choose k-1}_F+F_{k-1} {n-1 \choose k}_F$, which is proved by conditioning on whether the lattice path ends with a vertical step or horizontal step.

> Combinatorial Proofs of Fibonomial Identities (with Elizabeth Reiland*) The Fibonacci Quarterly, Vol. 52, Number 5, pp. 28-34, December 2014. https://www.fq.math.ca/52-5.html